# Java FindBugs: Suspicious comparison of Long references

Tags: java, findbugs

FindBugs recognizes the following bug in my code:

> Suspicious comparison of Long references

I have tried Googling this particular error but with no luck. As far as I know comparing fields of data type `Long` should be done with `==` operator.

```
if (materialDefinition.getId() == definitionToRemoveFromClass.getId()) {
    //...
}
```

I am certain both methods `.getId()` return a `Long`.

Is this really an issue and if so, how do I fix it?

Comment: Are these longs the primitive type or are they the object? (java.lang.Long) They are 2 different things

Comment: In which version of FindBugs is this rule defined? I could not find it on the list of descriptions for version 3.0.1 (http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html), and would like to activate it, for enhanced code safety.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is this really an issue and if so, how do I fix it?

Yes, you're comparing *references* not values, so two different `Long` instances with identical values will result in that comparison being `false`. You should use [`Long#equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) instead:

```
final Long id1 = materialDefinition.getId();
final Long id2 = definitionToRemoveFromClass.getId();

if (id1.equals(id2)) {
    //...
}
```

If `getId()` can return `null`, then also be sure to include the appropriate `null` check (although `getId()` doesn't sound like a method that should be returning `null`).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to do something like this.

```
public static boolean equals(Long a, Long b){
    if (a==null && b==null) return true;
    else if ((a==null) != (b==null)) return false;
    else return a.equals(b);
}
```

Comment: Or just use `Objects.equals(a, b)`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use `if (materialDefinition.getId().equals(definitionToRemoveFromClass.getId()))`

Be sure that `materialDefinition.getId()` is not null.

To compare these values (< >) you can use `.compareTo()` method :

A == B: `A.compareTo(B) == 0`

A < B: `A.compareTo(B) < 0`

A > B: `A.compareTo(B) > 0`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's a bad smell, and you should use the `equals()` method instead, as explained @arshajii above.

What I've found most intriguing is the fact that such comparison might even work sometimes, like starting with small values (-128 to 127), and will break for larger numbers. For example:

```
@Test
 public void compareSmallIds() {
     Long id1 = 127L;
     Long id2 = 127L;

     Assert.assertTrue(id1 == id2);
     Assert.assertTrue(id1.equals(id2));
     Assert.assertTrue((long) id1 == (long) id2);
     Assert.assertTrue(id1.longValue() == id2.longValue());
 }

@Test
 public void compareIds() {
     Long id1 = 500L;
     Long id2 = 500L;

     Assert.assertFalse(id1 == id2);
     Assert.assertTrue(id1.equals(id2));
     Assert.assertTrue((long) id1 == (long) id2);
     Assert.assertTrue(id1.longValue() == id2.longValue());
}
```

It seems this behavior is based on number cache policy definition, with byte values range as default. But definitely, code with non-primitive values should not rely on the `==` operator for value comparison!